# Cannot coerce class ""powerCurve"" to a data.frame

Tags: r, statistics

Trying to solve an issue with an R Code my employer has provided me. I'm not particularly experienced with R so I apologize if this is something simple. I tried searching for it but the other responses seems very specific to their problem, so they didn't help.

I am getting this error when attempting to export my data to Excel.

> Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
>     cannot coerce class ""powerCurve"" to a data.frame

I am running this block of code from a larger equation.

> ##Checking # replications
>   RepMax=aggregate(Rep~Trial, max, data=Power_Select1)
>   mean(RepMax$Rep)
>
> ##verifying fixed effect
>   fixef(Model_ISA_Power)
>
> ##assigning newfix effect---Yield Differences  1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6  bu/acre
>   fixef(Model_ISA_Power)["TRTManure+50"]=1.0
>
> modelTrial = extend(Model_ISA_Power, along="Rep", n=20)
>
> ##Replications
>
> \Reps_Bushel_1 <- powerCurve(modelTrial, along="Rep", alpha=.05, nsim=100,    > breaks=3:15)
>   print(Reps_Bushel_1)
>
> xlsx.writeMultipleData("OutputTest.xlsx",
>         Reps_Bushel_1)

Is there anyone out there that can help me identify how to get this information into Excel, or at least why I receive the Coercion error?

When I run the script, I get data formatted like this:

```html
> print(Reps_Bushel_1)
Power for predictor 'TRT', (95% confidence interval),
by largest value of Rep:
      3: 12.00% ( 6.36, 20.02) - 18 rows
      4: 11.00% ( 5.62, 18.83) - 22 rows
      5: 10.00% ( 4.90, 17.62) - 28 rows
      6: 10.00% ( 4.90, 17.62) - 34 rows
      7:  7.00% ( 2.86, 13.89) - 40 rows
      8:  8.00% ( 3.52, 15.16) - 44 rows
      9:  5.00% ( 1.64, 11.28) - 50 rows
     10:  7.00% ( 2.86, 13.89) - 56 rows
     11:  9.00% ( 4.20, 16.40) - 62 rows
     12:  8.00% ( 3.52, 15.16) - 66 rows
     13: 10.00% ( 4.90, 17.62) - 72 rows
     14: 10.00% ( 4.90, 17.62) - 78 rows
     15: 10.00% ( 4.90, 17.62) - 84 rows
```

We are trying to get the information from 3: to the end to export to Excel.

Comment: Please read the documentation of the function powerCurve(), section **Value**

Answer (score 2):

It looks like objects of class PowerCurve are not stored as data frames.

The first thing you should do is to look at the structure of your object:

```
str(Reps_Bushel_1)
```

I suspect this object has several components, each with different names, as seen via the command:

```
names(Reps_Bushel_1)
```

Let's say the components are named `component1`, `component2`, etc. Then you can extract the component you are interested in - say, `component1` - and check its structure:

```
str(Reps_Bushel_1$component1)
```

If the structure is a "data.frame" or even "matrix", you would be able to export `Reps_Bushel_1$component1` out of R without any problems.  If it is not, then we'd need more details to be able to help.

Comment: I was able to run names(Reps_Bushel_1) and get the list of components out of it. After checking each one, I am not seeing any of them that contain the information needed. What information would be needed to solve this problem?

Comment: Was your powerCurve object produced using functionality from the simr package? It's possible that the function prints one thing on the screen and stores the information to be printed in various bits and pieces. You could use sink() to capture what is printed on the screen in a text file, I guess.  But then you would need to read that text file back into R, find a way to read the components you need from it, store those components into a data frame and export the data frame.

Comment: I'll give that a try at work on Monday. I appreciate the help.